# Pyparsing: Problem splitting up a check in 2 seperate parts, where it should continue the check with the 2nd part if the check on the first part fails

Tags: python-2.7, pyparsing

For our client we have defined a domain-specific (Auto)test (SCript)-language to simplify setting up testcases.

Each test in an ASC-file consists out of three parts:

```
test <name> - <options> # <-- defines the start of a test and some general options
    <testheader>        # <-- contains a number of header commands which need to be always filled in
    <testbody>          # <-- the real test-actions
```

Both in a `<testheader>` and `<testbody>` whitelines are allowed (to make the testcases better readable)

To check if the definitions in these ASC-files are correct we have made a validator-script which checks the tests in the following way:

```
# definitions of valid_header_command and valid_test_command not listed here since they themselves are not of importance for the question (just lists with definitions of keywords for those particular sections)
anyotherline = restOfLine - Optional(LineEnd())

test_command = NotAny(OneOfKeywords('if', 'elif', 'else', 'fi') | eot) - (valid_header_command | valid_test_command | anyotherline)

block = Forward()
pre_post_block = Forward()

if_statement = Keyword('if') - vp_expression - eol
then_block = ZeroOrMore(block)
elif_block = Keyword('elif') - vp_expression - eol - ZeroOrMore(block)
else_block = Keyword('else') - eol - ZeroOrMore(block)
fi_statement = Keyword('fi') - eol

conditional_block = if_statement - then_block - ZeroOrMore(elif_block) - Optional(else_block) - fi_statement
block << ( OneOrMore(test_command) | conditional_block ) # pylint: disable=expression-not-assigned

test_implementation = (OneOrMore(block) + eot).setParseAction(self._parseaction_validate_mandatory_header_commands)

test_name = CharsNotIn(' +:!,?;@=()\n\r')
test_options = ( #option-definitios
               )
test_definition = Keyword('test') - White(' ') - test_name.addParseAction(self._parseaction_validate_unique_testcase).addParseAction(self._parseaction_reset_per_testcase_data) - test_options - eol
# if we can't find a test_definition, but we can find a line with something on it (so not the end of file), then report an error
testcase = (test_definition - test_implementation) | (restOfLine + ~StringEnd() + LineEnd()).setParseAction(self._parseaction_errorExpectingNextTest)
```

This works for the biggest part, but we saw that some strange behaviour was happening when somebody put an `if` around the `<testheader>` commands to prevent having to code 2 testcases which only differ in the header.

After long deliberation we decided that an `if` around the `<testheader>` commands is not allowed, since it is very rare that only the `<testheader>` differs.

So now we want to change the implementation in such a way that it does not allow `if` statements around a `<testheader>` anymore. To do this we wanted to try an approach like we did for `testcase` where a seperate check for `test_definition` (which defines the `test` keyword) is used before the rest of the `<testheader>` and `<testbody>` are checked.
(Note: we must stay backwards compatible, since the `if` around header-sections are almost never used).

What we tried was:

- Split up the old `test_command` in a `header_command` section and a `test_command` section (only the changed code from the snippet above):

  ```
  header_command = NotAny(OneOfKeywords('if', 'elif', 'else', 'fi') | eot) - (valid_header_command)
  test_command = NotAny(OneOfKeywords('if', 'elif', 'else', 'fi') | eot) - (valid_test_command | anyotherline)
  ....
  test_implementation = OneOrMore(header_command).setParseAction(self._parseaction_validate_mandatory_header_commands) + OneOrMore(block) + eot
  ```

  For the `<testheader>` commands this solution is working. But now it fails on every `<testbody>` command since they do not match with the `header_command` section, where we would like that it continues with the `test_command` section if it fails in the `header_command` section.

  Note again: whitespaces are allowed both in header- and body-sections, so we cannot use those as delimiters. And we must stay backwards compatible, so it is difficult/impossible to introduce any other delimiter.
- We also tried keeping the original code but adding checks to the `valid_header_command` section, but that does not work since although the `conditional_block` definition is part of `block` it also contains `block` and thus only when the parts of `if` statements are already handled it will handle the remaining `test_command` part which contains the check in `valid_header_command`. So handling it there is Just Too Late.
- And lastly: We considered changing the `_parseaction_validate_mandatory_header_commands` method, but how can we make sure that when that fails it goes first to the `test_command` before really raising an error?
  Hence we did not follow that approach further at the moment.

We think that our original approach of splitting up the old `testcommand` into 2 sections is the correct one, but we are already breaking our heads for a number of days on this to get it to work. So we end up here asking for help.

--> Does anybody have an idea how we can make sure that after our validator sees that it is not a `<testheader>` command it continues to check against the `<testbody>` commands before raising an error?

Note: implementation is done in python 2.7 with pyparsing 2.3.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A colleague of me found a working solution.

He also split up the block into a part that includes all and a test-command only part and replaced the block sections in the if-stements with the test-command only block.
He also added some extra parseactions:

```
    test_command      = NotAny(conditional_construct | eot) - (valid_header_command | valid_test_command | anyotherline)
    no_header_command = NotAny(conditional_construct | eot) - (valid_test_command | anyotherline)

    block = Forward()
    no_header_block = Forward()

    if_statement = (Keyword('if') - vp_expression - eol).addParseAction(self._parseaction_in_if_statement)
    then_block = ZeroOrMore(no_header_block)
    elif_block = Keyword('elif') - vp_expression - eol - ZeroOrMore(no_header_block)
    else_block = Keyword('else') - eol - ZeroOrMore(no_header_block)
    fi_statement = (Keyword('fi') - eol).addParseAction(self._parseaction_out_if_statement)

    conditional_block = if_statement - then_block - ZeroOrMore(elif_block) - Optional(else_block) - fi_statement
    block << ( OneOrMore(test_command) | conditional_block ) # pylint: disable=expression-not-assigned
    no_header_block << ( OneOrMore(no_header_command) | conditional_block ) # pylint: disable=expression-not-assigned
```

Comment: Nice solution. A minor note - if you use `<<=` operator for assigning Forwards, you may be able to drop the pylint directives, and you guard against the `a << b | c` problem (which you are doing using ()'s around the right-hand side).